# KeyError: 0 when iterating json through python-nmap

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, nmap

I'm trying to parse out specfic values from my dictionary. Having worked with dictionaries before, I was certain you could iterate through a length of results using integers.

Below is an edited example of my nmap scan (using fake IPs). I'm trying to access the `ipv4` values.

```
{'165.19.100.145': {'addresses': {'ipv4': '165.19.100.145'}}, '165.19.100.200': {'addresses': {'ipv4': '165.19.100.200'}}}
```

I'm trying to iterate through the dictionary like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import nmap
import json
nm = nmap.PortScanner()
results = nm.scan(hosts='165.19.100.0/24', arguments='-sP')

results_json = json.dumps(results['scan'], indent=4, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False)
json_data = json.loads(results_json)

scan_len = len(json_data)

for x in range(0, scan_len):
    ip_address = json_data[x]['addresses']['ipv4']
    print(ip_address)
```

When I run this script, I get a `KeyError: 0`. I have no idea why I might be getting this error. Wouldn't the `0` refer to the first `165.19.100.145`? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not iterating over a list but over a dictionary. there are no indexes in a dictionary afaik. 
**rather do this:**

```
for key, value in json_data.iteritems():
    print json_data[key]['addresses']['ipv4']
```

Comment: For python3 just replace `iteritems()` with `items()` and parenthesis around the print but this works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Why iterating over key and value and then not using `value` but using key just for getting the value‽ If you don't need the key, just iterate over the values.  That's `json_data.itervalues()` in Python 2 and `json_data.values()` in Python 3.